# which method is better for searching mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on php/mysql web site and i have to add in-site search. 
my site have these tables:

1. posts
2. category
3. tags
4. authors

The problem is, I can not decide which is better to search my relation DB:

1. indexing the data in another table using spider (like: sphider, sphinx,...).
2. or just search the data base directly.

Comment: thanks for answers but can please explain what is wrong with second choice it seems to be easier and straightforward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dedicated search products such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) are better, as their sole existence is to provide a search solution, and they do it very well. Whilst MySQL does support full-text search, it's only a feature of their core product.

There are many things, particularly in complex circumstances, that MySQL simply can't do. Take a look through the [Sphinx documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/) and you'll see plenty of examples.

Ultimately though, it depends on your use-case. If speed, scalability and advanced features aren't critical to the application, a dedicated search engine may well be overkill. It'd certainly be worth evaluating MySQL's [full-text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) as well, as if they satisfy your needs, it'll be a lot simpler to implement.

Comment: amm it is depending on the site requirements. i think for now I'm going to use mysql fulltext index and search, also i will start learning sphinx for future use

Answer (score 0):

First method. Try ElasticSearch, Sphinx.